# Thunderbird removes leading spaces before XML/HTML tags, how can I disable that feature?

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird, html

The following is especially annoying on XML / HTML / XSL / etc user groups and mailing lists. When I create a new plain-text message and type the following message in Thunderbird 9.0.1:

```
Check this code:
<hello>
    <world />
</hello>
```

it will be received as

```
Check this code:
<hello>
<world />
</hello>
```

Oddly enough, this behavior doesn't happen when a sentence doesn't start with a `<`-symbol. In my own Sent-folder the leading spaces are removed too. When I send as HTML mail, the problem doesn't appear. Does anybody know of a way around this?

EDIT: result of extensive comment-discussion have been moved into the body of the text.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. But my Thunderbird is set up to send plain-text messages only. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: @Oliver: I've tried both plain-text and formatted. Perhaps the message is send correctly, but the display if it is incorrect? I.e., I could try sending you a message and perhaps it looks OK on the other side. Note that not _all_ messages that I receive seem to have this problem.

Comment: I also viewed the received message in Thunderbird. It was displayed correctly. You might want to check the message source (Ctrl+U) and see if the spaces are in there.

Comment: @Oliver: it wasn't "all" messages, I seem to still receive messages with and without leading spaces from XML-style source. The Ctrl-U source is without spaces as well. When I look at the source of a draft-message, the `&nbsp;` leading spaces are all there...

Comment: @Oliver: I found something new. Sending with formatting keeps it. However, when sending in plain-text, it removes the leading space. When sending it mixed, and it's displayed in a plain-text mailing list, the leading spaces are gone as well.

Comment: Cannot replicate here either, even after I pasted your actual text in. using 9.0.1 in windows.  mabey it has something to do with how it went through some e-mail server?

Comment: @Psycogeek: didn't think of that possibility (and I'd find it odd if my message is tampered by my provider), but I'll investigate. However, it seems unlikely, because looking at my "Sent" folder, there too I see the messages without the spaces.

Comment: I dont know what is possible. didnt find anything on the web, except people generally saying that after sending a mail your at the mercy of the other side , and thier settings to have it seen the same way. . . So in "Draft", it was right, but in "sent" it is wrong? which indicates a change in formatting at your end, just like your saying.  is this both with plain and rtf and html?  I tried it 2 ways here.

Comment: In Options, Composition , General Tab, Check the Send Options.

Comment: @Psycogeek: what do you want me to check there? I've just tried once more and it's clear, both with the receiver as in my Sent folder, that (1) indentation in mail with HTML layout stays, (2) indentation with plain-text mail is removed.

Comment: I do not know, just observe there that a non html client send has options for changing to text, just looking for buttons that would effect it somehow

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I may've found why it wasn't replicable: it only happens when `mailnews.send_plaintext_flowed` is set to true (default). When set to false, the problem disappears. I've reported it as bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722654

Comment: @Abel Please remember to answer your own question if you found the solution.